# Symfony Doctrine get Many to Many Object (Shop & Category)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I'm a bit lost.

I would like to get a List with all shops with the Shopname and all the categories of the shop. For example
**Shopname: Leisure, Travel, Flights**

I think I make an error in reasoning. Following my code:

Here is the ShopRepository:

```
public function getCategoryAndShops() {
    return $this 
    -> createQueryBuilder('s') 
    -> select('s, c') 
    -> leftJoin('s.categoryShop', 'c') 
    -> getQuery() -> execute();
}
```

Here is the ShopController:

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //$entities = $em->getRepository('DbeDonaciBundle:Shop')->findAll();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('DbeDonaciBundle:Shop')->getCategoryAndShops();
    return $this->render('DbeDonaciBundle:Shop:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
```

Where are the mistakes and how should the index.html.twig looks like?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a relation in your entity you can go for something like this:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('DbeDonaciBundle:Shop')->findAll();
```

And in your template:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
      {{ entity.name }}:
      <ul>
          {% for cat in entity.categoryShop %}
          <li>{{ cat.name }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
     </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!It works perfectly, I expected it to be much more difficult!

Comment: Hey man, what if I want to display twice all categories but once just each category once? can I do restrictions withhin twig?

Comment: I don't understand correctly. can you add an an example of what you want to your question?

Comment: Hey I mixed up something, what i needed to do was to return two queries to the controller:
return $this->render('DbeDonaciBundle:Shop:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ));